# Correct way to add a print functionality to a java class

Tags: java, inheritance, decorator

Lets say I have `class Report` and I want to add a functionality `printReport(...)` and `shouldBePrinted(...)`. Printing it requires `GeneralPrinter` and `LanguageTranslator` which are given from outside. Furthermore, I should add members to make the `shouldBePrintable` method more optimized.

The way I see it there are three ways of doing it:

1. The simplest is to just add the members and functions to the `Report` class.
2. Create `PrintableReport` which extends Report and adds those members and functions.
3. Use the decorator pattern to add the needed functionality. (Not sure about that one. Please correct me if this is not the correct way to use a decorator.)

Am I missing some and which is the correct method to do it?

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve] rather than a vague description of the problem you're having

Answer (score 1):

Consider: Separation of concerns

At a HIGH level...

While it's not clear exactly what role `Report` fills, one might surmise it represents information organized in some fashion.

Rendering is a separate concern.  Often you'll want multiple ways to render: Generate PDF, HTML, XML, and/or print (postscript, other...).

So, perhaps you have multiple classes to work with `Report`, `GeneralPrinter`, `ReportPrinter`, ...

Comment: I see. You are right. The report should not be responsible for the printing, but only for the members which optimize the `shouldBePrinted` method.